Android Emulator on MacOS raises an error with MAUI
I'm using my iMac to work a bit faster on my .NET8 MAUI application and get it ready for all platforms. The project runs perfectly on my Windows 11 laptop. Now, I want to use MacOS because, unfortunately, it is easy to use Visual Studio for Mac because faster and easy to use.
I saw other post like this one in Stackoverflow but it is 10 years old and the technology is different from MAUI and the operating system is not defined.
In order to test iOS, MacCatalyst, and Android, I work on my iMac and Visual Studio for Mac (although it is not supported anymore). I created a new emulator for Android.

and then run the emulator.

The application is working on my Windows machine for Windows and Android and on my iMac for MacCtalyst and iOS. Unfortunately, when I run the app on the Android emulator on my iMac, I get this error

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlParseException: No embeddedresource found for PSC.Maui.Components.LanguageDropdown.LanguageDropdown
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.CreateValuesVisitor.Visit(ElementNode node, INode parentNode) in //src/Controls/src/Xaml/CreateValuesVisitor.cs:106
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode) in //src/Controls/src/Xaml/XamlNode.cs:189
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode) in //src/Controls/src/Xaml/XamlNode.cs:185
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode) in //src/Controls/src/Xaml/XamlNode.cs:185
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.RootNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode) in //src/Controls/src/Xaml/XamlNode.cs:242
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Visit(RootNode rootnode, HydrationContext visitorContext, Boolean useDesignProperties) in //src/Controls/src/Xaml/XamlLoader.cs:208
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(Object view, String xaml, Assembly rootAssembly, Boolean useDesignProperties) in //src/Controls/src/Xaml/XamlLoader.cs:78
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(Object view, String xaml, Boolean useDesignProperties) in //src/Controls/src/Xaml/XamlLoader.cs:53
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(Object view, Type callingType) in //src/Controls/src/Xaml/XamlLoader.cs:49
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[MainPage](MainPage view, Type callingType) in //src/Controls/src/Xaml/ViewExtensions.cs:37
at LanguageDropdownDemo.MainPage.InitializeComponent() in /Users/enrico/Projects/PSC.Maui.Components.LanguageDropdown/LanguageDropdownDemo/obj/Debug/net8.0-android/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.SourceGen/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.SourceGen.CodeBehindGenerator/MainPage.xaml.sg.cs:26
at LanguageDropdownDemo.MainPage..ctor() in /Users/enrico/Projects/PSC.Maui.Components.LanguageDropdown/LanguageDropdownDemo/MainPage.xaml.cs:9
at at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InterpretedInvoke_Constructor(Object obj, IntPtr* args)
at at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithNoArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithNoArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
at at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono(Boolean nonPublic, Boolean wrapExceptions)
at at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions)
at at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic, Boolean wrapExceptions)
at at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
at at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellContent.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.IShellContentController.GetOrCreateContent>b__0() in //src/Controls/src/Core/Shell/ShellContent.cs:76
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ElementTemplate.CreateContent() in //src/Controls/src/Core/ElementTemplate.cs:86
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.DataTemplateExtensions.CreateContent(DataTemplate self, Object item, BindableObject container) in //src/Controls/src/Core/DataTemplateExtensions.cs:23
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellContent.Microsoft.Maui.Controls.IShellContentController.GetOrCreateContent() in //src/Controls/src/Core/Shell/ShellContent.cs:81
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.Compatibility.ShellSectionRenderer.OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) in //src/Controls/src/Core/Compatibility/Handlers/Shell/Android/ShellSectionRenderer.cs:124
at AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.n_OnCreateView_Landroid_view_LayoutInflater_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_Landroid_os_Bundle(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_inflater, IntPtr native_container, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) in C:\a_work\1\s\generated\androidx.fragment.fragment\obj\Release\net6.0-android\generated\src\AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.cs:2031
at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPLLL_L(_JniMarshal_PPLLL_L callback, IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr klazz, IntPtr p0, IntPtr p1, IntPtr p2) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:363


The some project is working on my Windows machine. I don't understand what the problem is.

Does this error also happen on a default MAUI project?
